# Cannot save data by form_for Rails in Ruby : Unpermitted parameter: projectImages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I am trying to save form data by form_for
new.erb.html

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
  <h4>
    <label for = "projectName">Title(required)</label>
    <%= f.text_field :projectName, :maxlength => 50 %>
  </h4>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end -%>
```

ProjectsController

```
    class Com::A::B::C::ProjectsController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @projects = Project.all
      end

      def new
        @project = Project.new
        @allTags = Tag.all
        @allBenefits = Benefit.all
      end
def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)

    if @project.save
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:projectName)
  end
```

But nothings getting saved on the database

html tags for text_fiels looks like,

```
<input id="com_a_b_c_project_projectName" type="text" name="com_a_b_c_project[projectName]" size="50" maxlength="50">
```

I tried adding `url=>"com_a_b_c_project_path"` still nothing persists
I am new to rails in ruby, so any help would be nice.

Routes

```
namespace :com do
        namespace :a do
          namespace :b do
            namespace :c do
              get 'projects/index'
              resources :projects do
                 end
            end
          end
        end
      end
```

I get following exception:

**param is missing or the value is empty: project**

Request

```
Parameters:
"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"",
 "com_a_b_c_project"=>{"projectName"=>"s"
 "commit"=>"Create Project"
```

rake rotes

com_a_b_c_projects_index GET    /com/a/b/c/projects/index(.:format)    com/a/b/c/projects#index
      com_a_b_c_projects GET    /com/a/b/c/projects(.:format)          com/a/b/c/projects#index
                                      POST   /com/a/b/c/projects(.:format)          com/a/b/c/projects#create
   new_com_a_b_c_project GET    /com/a/b/c/projects/new(.:format)      com/a/b/c/projects#new
  edit_com_a_b_c_project GET    /com/a/b/c/projects/:id/edit(.:format) com/a/b/c/projects#edit
       com_a_b_c_project GET    /com/a/b/c/projects/:id(.:format)      com/a/b/c/projects#show
                                      PATCH  /com/a/b/c/projects/:id(.:format)      com/a/b/c/projects#update
                                      PUT    /com/a/b/c/projects/:id(.:format)      com/a/b/c/projects#update
                                      DELETE /com/a/b/c/projects/:id(.:format)      com/a/b/c/projects#destroy

**NOTE
I can save data with form_tag** 
But not with form_for...
However I need to use form_for otherwise I have to bind object to each field

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'create', :controller => 'projects' do %>
<h4><label for = "projectName">Title(required)</label> <%= text_field 'project', 'projectName'> </h4>
```

Cheers

Comment: If it returns error, show us. And also show your routes because you have namespace `Com::A::B::C::` in your controller.

Comment: what routes are you define?

Comment: I get following exception:

param is missing or the value is empty: project

app/controllers/com/a/b/c/projects_controller.rb:59:in `project_params'
app/controllers/com/a/b/cp/projects_controller.rb:20:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

    {"utf8"=>"✓",
     "authenticity_token"=>"",
     "com_a_b_c_project"=>{"projectName"=>"s"
     "commit"=>"Create Project"}

Comment: Routes

     namespace :com do
            namespace :a do
              namespace :b do
                namespace :c do
                  get 'projects/index'
                  resources :projects do
        
                  end
        
                end
              end
            end
          end

Comment: @Newbie did you add create method in controller?

Comment: What does the params section of your controller look like?

Comment: Yep @uzaif It looks like

Comment: can you show your rake routes

Comment: do you have project_name field in table?

Comment: NOTE I can save data with form_tag But not with form_for... However I need to use form_for otherwise I have to bind object to each field

Comment: Could you please post your create and project_params of controller.

Comment: Just updated @BradAxe

Comment: if you change params.require(:project) to params.require(:com_a_b_c_project) does that fix it...? Not sure if that is proper

Comment: OMG you are the best @BradAxe!!!!! Can't thank you enough.. IT WORKED!!

Comment: Imma post it as answer, please accept :p no problem!

Comment: As an aside, you might start out with using snake_case for model attribute names instead of camelcase, and note that this is probably not the only namespace issue you will have.  Welcome to rails and good luck

Answer (score 2):

The [Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) provide information on using `form_for` with namespacing in section 2.3.1:

> If you have created namespaced routes, `form_for` has a nifty shorthand
>   for that too. If your application has an admin namespace then
>
> `form_for [:admin, @article]`
>
> will create a form that submits to the `ArticlesController` inside the
>   admin namespace (submitting to `admin_article_path(@article)` in the
>   case of an update). If you have several levels of namespacing then the
>   syntax is similar:
>
> `form_for [:admin, :management, @article]`

So in your case it looks like it would be:

`form_for [:com, :a, :b, :c, @project]`

Comment: This is the proper way:)

Comment: This throws me error undefined method `com_a_b_c_com_a_b_c_projects_path' for #<#<Class:0x9238530>:0x922d7d8>           actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:220:in `polymorphic_method'

Comment: def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:projectName, :briefDesc, :whatSection, :challengers, :status, :valueProposal, :maturityLevel,:tag_ids =>[])#tag_ids: []
  end

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you are requiring a 'project' param by the line:

```
params.require(:project).permit(:projectName)
```

But looking at the request, the param being sent is 'com_a_b_c_project'.

If you change it to:

```
params.require(:com_a_b_c_project).permit(:projectName)
```

all should be well.

Comment: not trying to be a sore sport or anything, but it's probably better to mark my answer correct since it uses the proper style as indicated by the rails docs